# GeoPackage with German Umlauts not working with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I created a GeoPackage file with different names for the table which contains the geometry information.

First I tried the German "Gebäude" and I could not open the GeoPackage file with QGIS. Then
I replaced "Gebäude" with "building" in exactly the same database and it worked.

PS: Unfortunately I could not upload this GeoPackage file here to have a look at.

Comment: Just tried with no issues. Which QGIS version do you use and how **exactly** did you create the GeoPackage? _But in any case I suggest to never use special characters for this usecase unless absolutely necessary._

Comment: I tried as well with `ogr2ogr -f gpkg umlaut.gpkg test.shp -nln "Gebäude"`. No issues. GeoPackage is using only UTF-8 by the standard so obviously there is some misconfiguration in your system.